# Jmeter-How to sent the variable value to the response of particular Request

Tags: http, variables, jmeter, request, response

I am working in Jmeter.
I need to sent the value for the variable name 'Reference' in the response of the particular request.
I am able to get the response using Bean shell Post processor using the string "vars.put("response", new String(data));"
I need the get the variable 'Reference' which is referred by id as    id="reference"

I need to pass value to the variable 'Reference'.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting so if you want to store the response into the `Reference` JMeter Variable you can do it as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which response you want to store
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put("Reference", prev.getResponseDataAsString());
   ```

   where:

   - `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
   - `prev` stands for the parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

   see JavaDoc for the above shorthands for all available functions/properties description and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) for comprehensive explanation with examples for the above and other JMeter API shortcuts available for Groovy scripts

Comment: I got the Response..But Now I need to give value for the variable 'reference' in the response which I got.